# How do I set required gas fee to zero for localhost on Metamask?

Tags: truffle, metamask, truffle-contract

I'm doing a Solidity tutorial and trying to get a React example up and running.  I've got Truffle running and when I run `npm start` and Chrome connects to localhost, Metamast says "Insufficient Funds". The tutorial says to click "Edit" and set the min gas fee to zero.  When I do this, however, it won't let me.  Is there some other setting I can use? [image]

**EDIT**
I'm using Metamast version 10.8.1.

Comment: What version of Metamask do you use? Did you configure your node to accept zero gas price?

Comment: I'm using Truffle, and I didn't change any settings.  What setting would I change in Truffle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying contract with no cost (gasPrice 0) on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68387/deploying-contract-with-no-cost-gasprice-0-on-private-network)

Answer (score 1):

I got around this another way. When you type "truffle development" into a terminal it will output 10 accounts (along with 10 keys which correspond to those accounts). Take one of those keys and go into MetaMask, select import account, provide the private key. It'll then allow you to connect this new account which begins with 100 ETH. You can then use that account to run this example.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hack in the course: set the gas fee to something very, very low like 0.0000000001 and it works.

I still don't understand why I need gas for my local truffle server, and if I do, why the account doesn't offer a way to get some test eth to use.  Maybe I'll learn all this later in the tutorial.